# how to find length of an unsigned char pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof, strlen

I want to find size or length of an unsigned char pointer in a function where that pointer is an argument to that function.Near the pointers declaration size is coming correctly.

But when i am trying to find size in function it is giving 4.

How can i do this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//void writeFile(unsigned char *da);
void writeFile(char *da);
int main(int arc,char **argv)
{

 unsigned char block_bmp[]=
{
   0x0,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x0,0x0,0x0,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x0,0x0,0x0,0xff,0xff,0xff,//*16bytes*
};
printf("size::%d\n",sizeof(block_bmp));
writeFile(block_bmp);
}

//void writeFile(unsigned char *da)
void writeFile(char *da)
{
printf("%d\n",__LINE__);
printf("size::%d\n",sizeof(da));
printf("length::%d\n",strlen(da));
FILE *fp;
int i;
fp=fopen("/tmp/hexfile","wb");
for(i=0;i<3780;i++)
    fprintf(fp,"%c",da[i]); 
//  fwrite(da,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(da),fp);
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You're confusing the *size* of a type, and the *length* of a string.  If you want the latter, just use `strlen`.

Comment: can you upload your code. It can make your question more clear.

Answer (score 4):

If it points to a NULL-terminated string, use `strlen`. If not, the pointer is just some memory address for the called function, without any additional information about the size of the array (I assume, you try to pass an array). I suggest passing the number of array elements as additional parameter to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I cannot ask user to pass number of array elements .  I should write a method so that user can pass Unsigned char pointer as an argument to my method.  In my method i have to find its length.

Comment: @QtUser: If it's a string, then you have a solution.  If it's not a string (i.e. not null-terminated), then there is no solution.

Comment: Nitpicking: C-"strings" are either `NUL`- or `0`- or `null`-terminated. `NULL` is something different.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `sizeof` in this condition. You should be using the `strlen` if the char array is NULL terminated.

When you pass **array to a function, it decays to pointer**, you can't use `sizeof` on this pointer to get the size of the array. The `sizeof` will give you 4 bytes (assuming 32 bit machine).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int myArray[10])
{
    int i = sizeof(myArray);
    printf("Size of myArray = %d\n", i);
}
int main(void)
{
    // Initialize all elements of myArray to 0
    int myArray[10] = {0}; 
    fun(myArray);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
/**************OUTPUT**************
Size of myArray = 4
***********************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char array[100];
// sizeof(array) == 100

unsigned char* ptr = array;
// sizeof(ptr) == 4 for 32 bit platform.
```

When you call a function such as

```
 foo(unsigned char* ptr)
 {
 }
```

with 'array' as argument, you only see a 'unsigned char *', not an array with 100 elements. That's why 'sizeof' returns 4.

Comment: @R Sahu: exactly this is my problem.I guess my problen is not having proper solution.

Comment: @QtUser if you post more of your code, people here might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

pointers size `sizeof(any_pointer_variable)` will not depend on the datatype to which it is going to point. The size of the pointer is mostly 4 that is what you are getting in function. and it doesnt depend on what it points to. all pointers will have same size independent of what type they point to.

Comment: This is misleading, the size of a pointer has nothing to do with the size of an integer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ya. i told usually. since i found most of the time they are. ya its not necessary.

Comment: Is there any 64bit system that have `sizeof(int)` == 8? Never saw that, so 'usually' is wrong here.

Comment: ya ok. I made changes to my answer. Thankyou.